# Difficulties inserting a var element with insertAfter

Tags: javascript, jquery, var, insertafter

I have a var named Product1 (verified with alert)

```
var currentClass = $(this).parent().attr('class');
```

I have difficulties inserting it in my clone command - this does not work:

```
$(this).parent().clone(true).insertAfter(currentClass)
```

(if I put the name of the class it works)

```
$(this).parent().clone(true).insertAfter('.Product1')
```

I really do not know how to do it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle or something with your JS and HTML?

Comment: try `.insertAfter('.'+currentClass)`

Comment: @BeNdErR Thanks it works! Sub-question, what about if I have 2 classes, is there a way to specify the first or second one?

Comment: `.insertAfter('.'+currentClass+':eq(0))` for the first one, or `:eq(1)` for the second, etc.

Comment: You could use the element instead of a class like: `var currentElement = $(this).parent();` and `$(this).parent().clone(true).insertAfter(currentElement);`. This might be safer then relying on the position of the classname in your HTML.

Comment: @user3371049 please provide a fiddle with a working example for your 2nd request :)

Comment: @Ex-iT: `"." + this.parentNode.className.trim().split(/\s+/).join(".")`

Comment: Thanks all, you are great, for the second request: I have a workaround: will put a unique Id instead. @BeNdErR. Btw I am not a programmer, and I need a lot of help with cloning checkboxes on the go. I do it one step at a time with your help!!!

Comment: @user3371049 setting up a fiddle (www.jsfiddle.net), with a working example of your code, it's not that hard and it's really useful for anyone in this community to better understand your problem and give you a fast and precise hint :)

Comment: @BeNdErR - I have a JSFiddle for the base project (not up to date), cannot reflect reality though, I am working in a CMS environment + CKeditor (lots of constraints). Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergelie/ULywc/

Answer (score -2):

because you use string name class , and so selector work with "point"

```
$(this).parent().clone(true).insertAfter('.'+currentClass);
```

check you set vars , and log if it work